# Why doesn't my assert doesn't work in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my Custom VM options in My IntelliJ, I have "-ea" in my idea64.exe.vmoptions. But why doesn't this report assertion error:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
assert(a==b)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `idea64.exe.vmoptions` defines the java options which IntelliJ itself launches with; not what a given run configuration will launch with.

Once you've launched your program (via the little play icon next to your `main` method), it should appear in the run configurations drop down at the top.  If you go edit this, and add `-ea` to the VM Options field, you can then run it with assertions enabled.

Answer (score 3):

For Intellij 19.2 community version, I found the VM option to add -ea 
via going to top menu and following Run -> Edit Configurations... -> VM options:

Comment: This worked for me, and dropping a link to a reference i found with steps and pictures [Solved - Kotlin assert not working in IntelliJ IDEA](https://kotlinandroid.org/kotlin/kotlin-assert-not-working-in-intellij-idea/)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and none of the previous solutions were helping.

Turns out that was because of how my project was setup. If it's running "Current File" as the configuration, it will quickly get the kotlin template to run the current file.

So if that's the case, Edit Configurations -> Edit configuration templates (bottom left) -> Kotlin -> add -ea as a VM option

Answer (score 0):

Add the following arguments to the VM Options field: `-enableassertions` OR `-ea`

How to do this using the local file:
Go to Run | Edit Configurations | Modify options | add VM options | filed VM options

Alternatives:

1. Go to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | filed VM options
2. Or check out this article on Advanced configurations: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html?ysclid=lfy23e1f1778689033

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step for enabling assertions in intellige ide.

1. Run/Debug configurations
2. Modify options
3. Add VM options

Then add `-enableassertions` or `-ea`

[image]